# Retrieve value of the geocoder whithout map from mapbox

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using the whitout a map geocoder from mapbox, which is used in the example of the mapbox documentation.

However, I can't get the values that are returned.

I need the address selected by the user and, if possible, in gps longitude/latitude strings.

Here's my code :

```
<div id="geocoder" name="geocoder" class="form-control txt-field"></div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY TOKEN API';
    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        placeholder: 'point de depart'

    });

    document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd());
    geocoder.on('results', function (results) {
        document.getElementById('mapr').value = (results);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` event is called whenever the suggestions list is updated, to get the result **selected** by the user then you should listen to the `result` event.

```js
gecoder.on('result', e => {
  console.log(e.result)
})
```

I'm updating the official example to demonstrate this at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js-docs/pull/313/files

Comment: Thanks to you ! But how can I get the selected item only from a variable